# Matrix of a linear mapping in the new basis

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, change-of-basis

Let $N, M$ be a linear spaces over the same field $\mathbb{F}$. So $\{e_i\}$, $\{\overline{e_i}\}$ -- two bases in $N$ and $\{e_k'\}$, $\{\overline{e_k}'\}$ -- two bases in $M$. Let $f$ be a map between $N$ and $M$, $f: N \rightarrow M$, and between bases $\{e_i\}$ and $\{e_k'\}$ it will be $A_f$ and between bases $\{\overline{e}_i\}$ and $\{\overline{e}_k'\}$ it will be $\overline{A_f}$. Let $B$ be the basis change matrix $B(\{e_i\}) = \{\overline{e_i}\}$ and similar for $C$,  $C(\{e_k'\}) = \{\overline{e_k}'\}$.

So in my textbook I have this proof of the identity $\overline{A_f} = C^{-1} A_f B$:

$(\overline{e}_i)\overline{A_f} = f((\overline{e}_i)) = f((e_i)B) = (f(e_i))B = (e_i')A_f B = (\overline{e_i}')C^{-1}A_f B$

But I do not really understand why and how we can make follow steps: $\cdots = f((e_i)B) = (f(e_i))B = (e_i')A_f B = \cdots$. Why we can take the matrix $B$ beyond the parentheses? And why $f((e_i)) = (e_i')A_f$ and not $f((e_i)) = (e_i)A_f$?

Comment: I don't like your notation, and can't go no further.  Perhaps try identifying the linear transformations with their matrix, to simplify your question.

Comment: @HermitwithAdjoint I simply quoted my textbook and wrote out the notation from it.  What do you mean when you suggest replacing functions with matrices? A record of the form $A_f$ -- is a matrix of a map $f$

Comment: Do you know that if $v$ is a vector in $N$ written in the old basis then $B^{-1}v$ will  be written in the new basis?

Comment: $v = x_1 e_1 + \cdots + x_n e_n$, if we change basis, we will write that $e_i' = x_1^i' e_1 + \cdots + x_n^i' e_n$ for all $e_i'$ and $v$ in new basis will looks like $ v = x_1' e_1' + \cdots + x_n' e_n' = x_1'( x_1^1' e_1 + \cdots + x_n^1' e_n) + \cdots + x_n' ( x_1^n' e_1 + \cdots + x_n^n' e_n) = (x_1' x_1^1' + \cdots + x_n' x_1^n') e_1 + \cdots + (x_1' x_n^1' + \cdots + x_n' x_n^n') e_n $